# Not able to connect from javascript signalr client to azure client

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-signalr

Here is my stuff:

### Javascript:

```
 var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                .withUrl("/client/?hub=myHub")
                .withAutomaticReconnect().build();
```

OR

```
 var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                .withUrl("https://azure-service.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=myHub")
                .withAutomaticReconnect().build();
```

### C# Startup.cs:

```
    // Azure SignalR service
    app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
    });
```

Its getting following error:
400 - https://localhost:44324/client/negotiate?hub=myHub&negotiateVersion=1
Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `ConnectionString` in appsettings.json. It works for me. You also can [download my sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/Signalrdemo).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did added as well @Jason Pan

Comment: @Komal Using my sample code, can the program run normally?

Comment: Yes @Jason Pan i did tried by adding my connection string in your project and its worked for me.

Your stuff is helped for fixing my issue.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: can u please review this if you have idea, can u please help for this too much appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69254747/how-to-call-signalr-clientjavascript-from-background-services-like-from-api-on