# How to call SignalR client(javascript) from background services like from API on other port?

Tags: signalr

I am using @microsoft/signal on client end and azure Signalr on server end.

I did called SendAsync() from other api but its not worked for me.

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();

app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<MyHub>("/my");
        });
```

ITypedHubClient.cs:

```
public interface ITypedHubClient
{
    Task BroadcastMessage(string name, string message);
}
```

MyHub.cs:

```
    public class MyHub: Hub<ITypedHubClient>
     {
          public void Send(string name, string message)
          {
               this.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage(name, message);
          }
     }
```

In Service(Other API service which is in different port than signalR client):

```
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub, ITypedHubClient> hubContext;

   // After record will be updated 
   hubContext.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage("RefreshDetails", "test");
```

In javascript client:

```
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/my").withAutomaticReconnect().build();

        connection.on("BroadcastMessage", function (params) {
           //TODO
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller

Comment: InvokeAsync() is not supporting , tried with Solution 2 but not working its not giving any error too.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code and any errors you might be getting? Also, what your setup is in terms of tech etc. being used.

Comment: @97ldave i have edited the description.

Comment: @Komal thanks. Is the code in your javascript client correct? the .withUrl() should contain the url of your hub your connecting to. The endpoint in your startup class is "/myhub" and in .withUrl("/tic")

Comment: Yes, edited, its correct in my app. @97ldave

Comment: @Komal are you getting any errors?

Comment: No. Even    hubContext.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage("RefreshDetails", "test");
executed successfully but not able to trigger method of javascript client. @97ldave

Comment: @Komal does signalr connect on the client? is there a successful /negotiate request?

Comment: Yes, negotiate request is successful. @97ldave.